# Java: Would using setClip in Graphics be more efficient?

Tags: java, image, clip

I have an off screen `BufferedImage` that too large to be displayed all at once. So I'm using `getSubimage` to draw part of the entire image. I'm wondering if using `setClip` on the `Graphics` would use less resources. The docs say that "Rendering operations have no effect outside of the clipping area". How much of a difference would there be if I used a clip verses not using a clip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a clip on a `Graphics` object – for example a `Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100)` –
and then draw an image with that same `Graphics` object
– for example an image sized 300x300 –
the part of the image that lies outside of the clip is omitted. Only the top left 100x100 corner of the example would be drawn.

The main advantage to this is, that it speeds up the drawing process **a lot**. I'm not quite sure about *how* it makes it faster though; as a matter of fact I was looking this up right now.

In any case, I have found this to be very handy in designing full screen games. The more efficient you make your clips that draw to the screen, the smoother your game runs. When nothing is updating the screen components for a while, the clip stays empty, drawing nothing and leaving resources for game logic.

Comment: One more tip: an Area object can also be used as a clip. Areas can be added, subtracted, intersected, etc. This way you can build your clip any way you like.

Comment: Does anyone know if the speed-up is a function of the area of the clip or the area of its bounding box? (Thinking about drawImage(..).)